# Restarting a custom generator function for training new epochs in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I've written a custom generator to take my specific order of files and yield batches in a specific way. The generator is working fine and returning the batches as needed. The problem is: when training, I need more epochs to fully train the model but after being depleted in the first epoch, the generator is finished and doesn't return anything more in the next epoch.

Using `model.fit(dataset_generator(clean_path, noisy_path, denoised_path, noise_data, batch_size=4), verbose=1, epochs = 2, batch_size=4)` makes tensorflow return an exception as expected:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training.
> Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least
> `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 12 batches). You may
> need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

What is the best way to go around this? My generator also has a seed input to synchronize training and validation sets (very much likely the generators in keras), if I wanted each epoch to have different seeds would I need to write a custom `fit` function too?

The generator at the moment:

```
def dataset_generator(clean_path, noisy_path, denoised_path, noise_params, image_dimension=[512,512,3],
                      batch_size=32, shuffle=False, split=False, split_size=0.5, partition="training", seed=42):
    
    #Loading the file list for each of the datasets
    clean_list = listdir(clean_path)
    noisy_list = listdir(noisy_path)
    denoised_list = listdir(denoised_path)
    noise_data = np.load(noise_params)
    
    #Fixing the file order
    clean_list = sorted(clean_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split("."[0])[0]))
    noisy_list = sorted(noisy_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split("."[0])[0]))
    denoised_list = sorted(denoised_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split("."[0])[0]))
    
    #Setting conrol variables for trasversing the datasets
    dataset_size = len(noise_data)
    indexes = range(len(noise_data))
    index_counter = 0
    batch_index = 0
    
    #Returning infomartion on the dataset
    print("Folder " + clean_path + ": found " + str(len(clean_list)) + " files.")
    print("Folder " + noisy_path + ": found " + str(len(noisy_list)) + " files.")
    print("Folder " + denoised_path + ": found " + str(len(denoised_list)) + " files.")
    print("File " + noise_params + ": found " + str(len(noise_data)) + " entries.")
    
    #Verify if the files and the entries in noise file match   
    if(len(clean_list) != len(noisy_list) != len(denoised_list) != len(noise_data)):
        print("Datasets have different sizes. Aborting.")
        return
    
    #If shuffle was defined, permutate the indexes using a seed 
    if(shuffle):
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
        shuffled_indexes = rng.permutation(len(noise_data))
        indexes = shuffled_indexes
      
    
    #If 'split' was set, return the indexes of the partition selected in 'partition'
    if(split):
        split_point = np.floor(split_size*dataset_size)
        if(partition=="training"):
            indexes = indexes[:split_point]
        elif(partition=="validation"):
            indexes = indexes[split_point:]
    
    #Calculate the number of batches given the size of the partition used
    batch_total = np.floor(len(indexes)/batch_size)
    
    clean_batch = np.empty([batch_size, image_dimension[0], image_dimension[1], image_dimension[2]])
    noisy_batch = np.empty([batch_size, image_dimension[0], image_dimension[1], image_dimension[2]])
    denoised_batch = np.empty([batch_size, image_dimension[0], image_dimension[1], image_dimension[2]])
    maps_batch = np.empty([batch_size, image_dimension[0], image_dimension[1], 1])
        
    while True:
        #check if the batch number is still in valid range
        if batch_index > batch_total:
            break
    
        for i in range(batch_size):
            
            #read the clean image for index n
            clean_image = cv.imread(clean_path + clean_list[indexes[index_counter]])
            clean_image = cv.cvtColor(clean_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            clean_image = clean_image[np.newaxis,:,:,:]/255
            clean_batch[i,:,:,:] = clean_image
            
            noisy_image = cv.imread(noisy_path + noisy_list[indexes[index_counter]])
            noisy_batch[i,:,:,:] = noisy_image
            
            denoised_image = cv.imread(denoised_path + denoised_list[indexes[index_counter]])
            denoised_batch[i,:,:,:] = denoised_image
            
            map_matrix = np.ones([image_dimension[0],image_dimension[1],1]) * noise_data[indexes[index_counter]]
            maps_batch[i,:,:,:] = map_matrix
            
            index_counter =+ 1
        
        yield([noisy_batch, maps_batch, denoised_batch], clean_batch)
        batch_index +=1
```

Comment: your epochs are too long, the number of epochs does not matter

Answer (score 0):

No you are incorrect, the problem is not about the generator or the number of epochs, as the error is saying you are trying to PASS THE SAME DATA IN THE SAME EPOCH, your generator doesn't have enough data. He is not able to pass different data during an epoch, you dont need less epoch you need shorter epochs.

i don't know if you get it, you need do use the argument `steps_per_epoch` of `fit` to limit the length of an epoch.

This is happening because your generator is running out of new data before the epoch is finished.

Comment: I'm fully aware that I'm passing the same data, I was hoping that keras would call the generator again on a new epoch as my generator shuffles itself when restarted. The solution then might be making the generator generate sequences infinetely, which might be a problem, I'll try though, thanks.

Comment: my understanding has always been that keras ALWAYS calls the generator again at a new epoch, the problem here is that your network is not doing a new epoch, your network stops working during the first epoch, not during the new epoch, your network during the first epoch cant do ```next(generator)``` enough times